# Running two projects at once in Visual Studio 2010 - do not want

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

You may think this question is the exact duplicate of [Running two projects at once in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio). Not really, it is the exact opposite.

I have a VS 2010 solution with two MVC3 projects. I've already configured the solution with a single startup project. However, each time I run it, VS spawns two servers with the two MVC applications (and one does not have direct dependency on the other).

So, how do I get rid of such behavior?

Comment: Also asked at https://superuser.com/q/368430/8271

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the project you don't want to start up, go to the Properties tab, and change 'Always start when debugging' to False.

Comment: You, sir, hit the nail in the very head.

Comment: To be clear, you should not right click on the project and choose properties, rather left click on the project, switch to the Property Inspector tab (or view) and change Always Start when debugging there.

Comment: Select the project in solution explorer and press F4 to bring up the properties.

Comment: This setting is stored in the `.csproj.user` xml file which is not normally source-controlled so you'll have to do this on every machine. The setting is stored in `<AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>`