# The type 'StringPro.IMyString' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I receive this error when trying to run the client.

> The type 'StringPro.IMyString' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

This error comes from, StringProClient from file Program.cs and underlines in blue the following first line of code:

```
StringProProxy.StringProProxy proxy = new StringProProxy.StringProProxy();
```

The solution has 4 projects inside:

**StringPro** - Class Library that contains the service's interface(`IMyString.cs`) and the implementation class(`MyString.cs`)

**StringProHost** - Console Application that has Program.cs inside which defines `Uri`, `ServiceHost`, `Endpoint`, `ServiceMetadataBehaviour`, `HttpGetEnabled`, `host.Description.Behaviours`, calls `host.Open()` and displays in console information about when the service was started

**StringProProxy** - I believe it's a Class Library project since it has only `StringProProxy.cs` which defines the service's proxy

**StringProClient** - Console Application which instantiates the service's proxy inside, call the service's functions and displays results.

EDIT: The service host launches fine. It's the client that won't build and run because of the mentioned error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a project is using a type that was declared in other assembly, this assembly must be referenced - this is basically what your error is telling you.

In your case, I'm guessing that `StringProClient` is referecing `StringProProxy`, but it is also using types declared in `StringPro` project (to be exact: `IMyString` interface/class), without referencing it. You should make sure, that `StringProClient` references both, `StringProProxy` and `StringPro`.

Comment: Not usre if worked. Now I tried to run them and got: `Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'StringPro.IMyString' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.`

Comment: @Bob Well, this is completely different error. Previous one was a generic c# compiler one, now you have WCF one. You can check other SO.com question for it. For example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element

Comment: How do I run both Host and Client from one Visual Studio instance. Because if I run Host I can't run the Client since it disables the project viewer. If I try to run StringPro it won't run since it is a Class Library.

Comment: @Bob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio . You can also open project viewer after running first project, and r-click it and select Start instance. Those problems can be googled and are not relevant to your main question, it's a good practice to stick to one problem / topic in comments.

Comment: My bad. I found the solution but it wouldn't let me edit the previous comment for some reason. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Such problem mostly arises with the issues like namespace only. Kindly check your references as well as namespaces again.**