# VS2012: Multiple startup projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way of telling Visual Studio (2012) to launch multiple projects at start up?

I am currently working on a solution containing both the client and server sides of a program.

Starting under debug launches the client but to launch the server I need to follow `Server Project > Properties > Debug > Start new instance`

[image: VS2012, Debug , start new instance]

I'm fundamentally lazy, and this process is getting boring!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165413(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running two projects at once in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can go to your main Solution => right click => Properties => Tab: Common properties => Startup project => Multiple startup projects

There you can select all the projects you want to launch.

Answer (score 9):

if you right click on the solution, you can select an option called `Set StartUp Projects`

[image]

This gives you a dialog where you can select which projects you want to start

[image]

Comment: Very nice explanation David

Comment: If I have 2 startup projects (WinForms + WebService) how can I kill the WebService when the WinForms app is closed ?