# How to stop a WebService from C# WinForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

If I have 2 startup projects as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924393/vs2012-multiple-startup-projects).

One is a WebSite/WebService;
the other is a WinForms app.

How do I stop the Service when the C# WinForm app is closed.

**UPDATE**

Im running IIS Express within my Solution.

Ther are the 2 projects (WebSite/WinForms) When the WinForms app closes it must also stop the instance of IISExpress.

Im noticing that while debugging, I close the app but the Service is still running.

Comment: What do you want to stop, IIS, the app-pool of the service or what else?

Comment: This may help: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-start-or-stop-a-windows-service-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: The whole IIS. Not just the app pool. Actually its better just the AppPoool !

Comment: You haven't even mentioned the webserver, are you using IIS6 or IIS7? What are you actually trying to achieve, why do you need it at all?

Comment: You can click on "Stop Debugging" button in VS.

Comment: Yes but after I deploy how do I stop that local IISExpress ?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use IIS Express before but I guess it works over a process. So probably you will find and kill that process at all.

Checking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772092/starting-and-stopping-iis-express-programmatically) may help.