# How can I run multiple projects in VS 2012 at the same time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible for me to run multiple (2) projects at the same time?

I realize that you only have the option of making a single project the 'startup project'.

But I have 2 web projects in my solution, and I need to run both at the same time.

Is the only option opening multiple instances of VS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2012: Multiple startup projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924393/vs2012-multiple-startup-projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-Click on your solution (Top-Most node in your Solution
   Explorer)
2. Click on "Properties"
3. On the right panel, expand
   "Common properties", and click on "Startup Project"
4. Click on "Multiple Startup Projects"
5. In the "Action" column, select "Start" on the project you want to start
6. Optionally, you can change the startup order by clicking on a project and moving it with the arrows on the right.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is open another instance of VS and have each project open in the separate VS windows. Then I run both of them.

This saves the hassle of having to deal with changing the settings around.