# Run different projects in a Solution VS2o1o simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging

I have developed four projects of Fitness+Health Training of Windows Phone 7.1, now I want to Merge these projec in a single Solution. So it is easy to Add an Existing Project and then run each project as a start up project, but the Question is: How to access to each project, just on a Button click... Let see the example.

[image: Home Screen]

As u see, All projects are independently work, each Project have different UI. Now if I click on the 1st Button, the PushUps Trainer App should be run, and If I click on the 2nd Button the SitUps Trainer App should be run and so on....

**so How it is possible to run different solutions inside a main solution simultaneously...?**

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio

Comment: do you want to merge 4 apps into 1 app? Or create 1 app that can run the other 4 apps if installed?

Comment: Yes, I want ur 2nd Option almost, Want to Run the Other 4 apps which already been developed. Keep in mind, that my apps are not depend upon each other, each app has different senario.

Comment: I mean not client and Server type app.

Comment: Is it possible to run the XAP file of each App on Button click, because these apps are separtly been developed and its XAP file is also available, so that the main page will be (as shown above) and then on click event of each button will launch the relevant app.