# How Could I Debug 2 Application at same time in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have Solution that contain 2 projects
1- Windows App(contain Form)
2- Web App (Contain Default.aspx)
and i want them to open at same time 
How could I do this ?

Comment: See this link - there's a configuration in VS to do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another scenario. You set your Web App project directory as virtual directory in IIS and it runs. You can go `http://localserver/..../default.aspx`... Then you can run your Windows application by pressing F5 if it is set as startup project, or go to `project-debug-start new instance`. At this point you debugging your windows app. Now, go to `tools-attach to process` and attach to your web application process. Voila - you debugging both applications/projects at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to open a second Visual Studio instance, debug the Windows App with the first instance and the Web App with the second instance. Keep in mind that this costs some performance on your PC.

Comment: OK., but could be a way to debug windows app and from it create any function or  procedure or (button) to execute the second solution ?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by *execute the second solution*? Just want to call it or want to start it, f.e. in debug mode? Nevertheless, a better way than mine is  provided by @Rob in the comments to your question.