# How to run tests before program?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have 2 projects: One of them is my program's project and the another one is my program's test project. I have setted my test project as my startup project, but when I run my program, the Visual Studio runs only the tests. If I try to set my program's project as my startup program, my tests do not run. There is a way to run both simultaneously? Or run the tests before my program?

Comment: Why would you want to run the tests every time you run your program?

Comment: @brian To be sure that nothing is going wrong and to better control what is running. Is that possible?

Comment: No, you want to run your tests every time you _build_ your program after a _change_, not every time you _run_ your program.

Comment: @john Yes, but I'm developing my code. I'm always changing and I want to run my tests with my program, so I don't need to always change the startup project when I want to see the tests results and see what is happening with my program

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? VS2013 can be configured to discover and run your unit tests on every local build, in the background.

Comment: @john I'm using VS2010

Comment: That's a good reason to upgrade. It's a very nice feature. It not only finds and executes your tests on every build - it does that in the background, so you don't have to wait for them to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run two projects like that. But when one of your project is running, you can:
1.  "right click" on another project
2. Go to "Debug" 
3. Go to "Start New Instance".

You can run your both projets.. 
Try it..

Reference Link:  http://iamfixed.blogspot.de/2017/10/run-multiple-projects-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: This is not true - you can configure VS (at least some editions) to start multiple projects at the same time (running test along with program sounds strange... but possible).

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but would having multiple start up projects be a potential solution? If so, here is [how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio)