# Can we run Windows, iOS and Android projects in Xamarin at the same time rather than individually?

Tags: xamarin

We can set any project as a strartup project and debug in Visual Studio-Xamarin. I want to know if there is a way by which we can run the Android, Windows and iOS projects simultaneously on their emulators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running two projects at once in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment by @SushiHangover I also suggest you check out the Channel 9 Xamarin Show clip [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-2-iOS-Simulators) right around the 7:52 mark where James shows how to run multiple Visual Studio iOS simulators at the same time. Note that it does require Visual Studio 2015.

This does not necessarily allow you to debug multiple simulators at the same time though.