# Running multiple projects at once in Visual Studio only specified project

Tags: visual-studio

I have seen this:
[Running two projects at once in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio)

But I have another problem.

My solution had many executable projects.

Maybe I can allocate them into different groups.

For each group, It has a specific one or more startup projects.

So how can I configure it with Visual Studio 2017?

(Could I making some configuration in the project properties?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SwitchStartupProject](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProjectforVS2017) extension to select the startup project from a dropdown and switch between multi-project startup configurations.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's useful.