# WCF in webjob returns list of records to webapp

Tags: wcf, azure, web-applications, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Is this possible to put WCF in webjob that will return list of records to webapp.Actually I have project that returns search results (searching is done via lucene.net). Is there any guide or way to get results in my webapp from webjob?

Also can anyone guide me on my localhost I am running my webapp and web job is part of same solution. When I run web application, main function of WebJob is not hitting. Web app and web job can run simultaneously? If these are not runs simultaneously then How can I invoke my searching project initially ? How can my web project relate with my web jobs? I know about invoking by queue but some functions should be run initially when web application is started.

I want to test this behavior on my localhost

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible to put WCF in webjob that will return list of records to webapp.Actually I have project that returns search results (searching is done via lucene.net). Is there any guide or way to get results in my webapp from webjob?

As I known, Azure WebJobs provide you with an easy way to run scripts or programs as background process in the context of your Azure Web Apps. You could not get results directly from WebJobs in your Web Application, you need to store your results in a central data center (Azure Queue, Table Storage,Service Bus,etc.), then you need to retrieve the data explicitly in your Web App. Here is a official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started) about web application working with Azure WebJob.

> Also can anyone guide me on my localhost I am running my webapp and web job is part of same solution. When I run web application, main function of WebJob is not hitting. Web app and web job can run simultaneously?

You could right click your solution and select `Properties`, choose `Startup Project` under `Common Properties`, choose `Multiple startup projects` and configure the Action for your web application and your WebJob. For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio).

**UPDATE:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for you answer, I am using Lucene.net that creates indexes of search results and after it indexes results search project can directly filters results from indexes created no need of database calls. As you said web job results can store into queue or table storage that will be equivalent to database calls that will be double work I think first web job indexes results and then store into queue or table storage then web project query to storage to get results.

Comment: setup multiple projects as start up projects - I think there is misunderstanding  to get my point I was trying to ask webjob and web app runs dependently on each other or separately ?

Comment: can you please come on chat?

Comment: As I known, web app and webjob runs separately. WebJob could be deployed separately or you could add your webjob project to your web application, then it could be deployed when you deploy your web application to Azure. When deploying the webjob to azure, it would be located in `app_data\jobs` folder of your web app and the kudu site would launch your webjobs, you could see the screenshots from my update.

Comment: do you have seen my invitation of chat room? Can you please give me your few minutes on chat?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139371/wcf-in-webjob-returns-list-of-records-to-webapp).

Comment: I sent you messages over chat. Please reply. I want to know about possible solutions of my scenario

Comment: I have entered the chat room, let us continue this discussion.