# Debugging two .NET Core projects in Visual Studio at once

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have two .NET Core 2.0 projects, both in the same solution. A Web API project and a Web ASP.NET MVC  project. The ASP.NET MVC projects consumes the [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release) project.

Is it possible to debug both projects in Visual Studio at the same time or do I need to run one from the command line using dotnet.exe and debug the other?

I would like to end up being able to debug both, place breakpoints in both and for Visual Studio to jump between projects while debugging.

NB: This is in Visual Studio 2017, *not* [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

Comment: I've never actually tried this, but you can set multiple startup projects. I believe that's what it's for.

Comment: I read that somewhere already but if I select a different project as startup it deselects my original. Also if I select two projects at the same time I don't have an option for setting as startup.

Comment: Right-click on the solution, not the project then click on "Select Startup Projects..."

Comment: Got it, works now thanks. If you put that in as an answer I can accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running two projects at once in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can set multiple startup projects to run/debug two projects at once:

1. Right click on the solution in the *Solution Explorer* and select *Properties*.
2. Under *Common Properties\Startup Project* select *Multiple startup projects* and set the *Action* to be *Start* for the two projects that you want to debug.