# Visual Studio 2017 Console not showing but running

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a problem where a Console app window is not showing during debugging when there is also a .NET Core web app inside the same solution. The console app code runs fine, just no black console window.

Visual Studio: Version 15.5.6
Microsoft .NET Framework: Version 4.7.02556

Console App: Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1
Web App: Target Framework: .NET Core 2.0

If I create a separate .sln and add the .NET Framework console app to it, the window shows during debugging. Both the Core 2 web and the .NET Framework console share a .NET Standard library.

Comment: try deleting the .vs folder in your project directory

Answer (score 9):

I was suffering from the same problem on an inherited legacy application.

The issue here was that although the application had the structure of a Console App, it was actually configured to run as a Windows App (with no code to show forms or anything).

[image]

To fix, I just changed Windows App to Console App in the project's Properties page.

[image]

Comment: I seem to be getting this with the latest VS 2019 v16.8.2 update. Toggling it back to "console application" doesn't "stick" - it keeps reverting back to "Windows application".

Comment: I'm having all sorts or problems since "upgrading" to v16.8.2. Sorry I can't be more help, but at least you know you're not alone!

Comment: I followed comments from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/169559/view.html): checkout  .proj file from source control (if you have it) > open it in notepad > remove " <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>"

Comment: Or <useWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>, and live with the build target warning "NETSDK1106 Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop requires 'UseWpf' or 'UseWindowsForms' to be set to 'true'"

Answer (score 7):

At the top of your Visual Studio IDE [image]

change the [image]

and in the drop down , select your Project name instead i.e) [image]

Comment: hey your steps is so simple but helping me a lot... i was messed up with many other & wasted time.,.,, thanks a lot.... i love it the way u put snapshot...
keep sharing the happiness...

Answer (score 3):

This is a genuine issue. I'm having the the exact same problem on all my development machines.

Visual Studio: Version 15.6.4 Microsoft .NET Framework: Version 4.7.02556

Console App: Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1 Web App: Target Framework: .NET Core 2.0

I've tried to unload/reload projects, changed target framework back and forth and a few other things. Nothing helps. Running my project from within VS2017 works the first 5-10 times when starting VS2017 and loading up my project. Then all of a sudden the console windows just stops showing when running/debugging from within VS2017. But the app is running in the background for sure.

UPDATE:

As earlier stated I did try to change the target framework of my problematic project back and forth. Instead of changing back and forth I tried to just change the target framework to 4.7.1 and keep it there. That resolved the issue.

Comment: Still an issue with aps.net core 3.1 wherein you cannot select 4.6.1 as a target framework.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment for clarification(don't have the reputation yet) did you set your console project as the start up project or the web project? You can switch between the two if you're trying to debug something on the console or on your site.

You can also unload/load your web project to switch between them. Whatever is easiest for you.

[image]

Right click on your project and click on 'Set as StartUp Project'.

If this option isn't available unload your web project by right clicking on that project and selecting 'Unload Project'. Try changing the startup project again.

Comment: Yes, I did that and no console shows. It should not even be necessary.

Comment: @Dranyar Try unloading your web project, setting your console as the startup project. Run your project.

Comment: @Dranyar You can unload your web project by right clicking on the project and clicking unload project. You can easily toggle between that and load.

Comment: I am using using two separate solutions/visual studio instances. I curious as to the reason it isn't working in the same solution.

Comment: @Dranyar have your checked out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio

Comment: The multiple startup project configuration is just a convenience feature so that you don't have to click on each project and do "Debug->Start" .

Comment: @Dranyar I think it's because both projects need to have a static void Main... so it knows where to start. When you select the start up option in visual studio it basically starts there at the beginning and works it's way down.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, Changed my Framework from 4.7 to 4.5 and  then again to 4.7 and it started working. Bit of weird but it worked for me.