# How to debug with 2 web API projects in visual studio solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, api, debugging

I have a visual studio solution with 2 projects in it. Both are web API's (not .net core). When I had one project I could debug it by hitting

```
http://localhost:53961/api/...
```

However I then added the 2nd project. How can I start debugging the second one? It doesn't seem to hit the breakpoint. I get

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
```

When I put a breakpoint on the main method

```
    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<Result> Get(string emails)
    {

    }
```

I see a message:

```
The breakpoint will currently not be hit. No code has been loaded for this code location.
```

Comment: Have you set the second apis port to a different from the first api?

Comment: How can I find out where that is set for both?

Comment: Project properties --> debug --> app url

Comment: If you want the api's to run on the same url, you need to make sure to load the assemblies from one api to the other. In .net core you only need to refere the project to the startup project..don't know if it's the same in net45>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set "Multiple startup projects". Right click on solution in solution explorer and then click properties. Common Properties->Startup Project and then select "Multiple startup projects" and then set the Action for both of your APIs to "Start"

[image]