# Accessing WebAPI using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web Application with multiple projects:

1. WebApp (Main website with aspx pages)
2. Domain (business logic and data access layer)
3. Api (webapi project)

I have added reference of Domain in API project, so that I can access the business logic and data layers in API. Here's my API Class:

```
public class ShoppingController : ApiController
{
        // GET api/shopping/GetShoppingCartItemsCount
        public int GetShoppingCartItemsCount()
        {
            ShoppingCartDetails shopping = new ShoppingCartDetails();
            var a = shopping.GetShoppingCart();
            if (a != null && a.Count > 0)
                return a.Count;
            return 0;
        }
}
```

When I access the above function from my localmachine, `localhost/api/shopping/GetShoppingCartItemsCount` it throws this error:

> resource not found

How do I access the above WebAPI from browser?

Comment: Are you calling api via jquery ajax?

Comment: would you please add you routing config

Comment: "*Accessing WebAPI using jQuery*" Where is the jQuery code in your question?

Answer (score -1):

Run multiple project together from following link [Running two projects at once in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio)
Then

```
$.ajax({  
          url: 'http://localhost:3413/api/shopping/GetShoppingCartItemsCount', //your api url  
          type: 'GET',  
          dataType: 'json',  
          success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {  
            console.log(data);  
             },  
                 error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                     console.log('Error in Operation');  
                 }  
             });
```

Comment: This solution isn't working for me, i enabled my WebApp and API projects as startup, now i am using the jquery function with api localhost/api/shopping/GetShoppingCartItemsCount but the api url does not gets resolved, also i tried accessing the api url separately in browser, and it throws the resource not found error as earlier.

Comment: would you please add attribute into your api method [HttpGet] then try to access.

Comment: Even that's not working, actually i have hosted my whole web application in IIS, and converted the WebApp and API project as Application, now i am accessing the API functions via localhost/api/shopping/GetShoppingCartItemsCount, and here i am getting resource not found error.

Comment: Check IIS directory has proper permission to access.