How to run multiple ASP.NET Core projects at the same time in VS Code?
I have 2 types of .NET projects, 1st is ASP.NET Core Web API (for backend) and the second is a Blazor WASM (for frontend).
Is it possible to configure these two projects to run at the same time using dotnet cli in VS Code?
In the example video, the instructor using only Visual Studio 2022. I don't have Visual Studio 2022, because it takes a lot of memory and works very slow on my machine so I deleted it long ago.

duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850019/running-two-projects-at-once-in-visual-studio

@MoJony seems to me the linked question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code, which is the opposite of what OP asks for.

to just run them, you don't even need Visual Studio Code, just use the command line dotnet run (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run). Of course they need to be compiled first. You can run it from a terminal inside Visual Studio Code, or even from a simple cmd / powershell terminal. Or you can also run two different Visual Studio Code instances.

Here I started a working sample.
1.Project structure

2.tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "msbuild",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            
        },
        {
            "label": "buildbackend",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Backend/Backend.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "buildfrontend",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Frontend/Frontend.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}

3.launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (Frontend)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "buildfrontend",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Frontend/bin/Debug/net8.0/Frontend.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Frontend",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
        },
        {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (Backend)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "buildbackend",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Backend/bin/Debug/net8.0/Backend.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Backend",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
          "name": "Frontend & Backend",
          "configurations": [
            ".NET Core Launch (Frontend)",
            ".NET Core Launch (Backend)"
          ],
          "stopAll": true
        }
      ]
}

Attention: value of preLaunchTask in laucnch need to be the same as label defined in tasks
4.Debug selected

multiple stared

